# Allow Specific Ip Address's To Access A Page On My Website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

So I am making a website that I can put games, music, live chat and tons of other things on there that all my friends and other people that visit the site can look at and enjoy, but I would like a few pages ( live chat and blog ) to be private to my friends ip's but I do not know how to do this. Currently, on the website, I am using HTML5, CSS & Javascript and am still learning the more complex languages like PHP and others but I am still open to trying. The site is currently hosted on my computer using a DNS address that others on my LAN can access but I will soon be moving my script to a proper hosting service once the website is ready for release.

Comment: IP Addresses are easily spoofed. Most public ISPs providing service to "friends and family" rotate IP addresses (change them) periodically. You've discovered the need for authorization. Congratulations.

Comment: It's easier to add a login system which ask for username and password than using IP

Comment: @catcon then how do I the page that I am trying to protect recognize and accept a user that has created an account and that I have then given permissions

Comment: There are plenty example on the Internet, this is one: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php

Comment: @catcon thankyou that is very helpful and does answer my question to a point

Comment: On top of the above comments, you will need to dabble a bit with sql, not much, just get the basics down.